# How to add from and to port in aws cdk?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-security-group, aws-cdk

Hi I am working on aws cdk. I have created earlier ingress rules using cloud formation as below.

```
 - IpProtocol: tcp
     FromPort: 31000
     ToPort: 65535
     SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref MerchWebServicesLoadBalancerSecurityGroup
```

I can add port 80 or 443 as below

```
mws_vpc_sg.connections.allow_from(mws_vpc_sg_alb,ec2.Port.tcp(443))
```

How can I specify from port 31000 and to port 65353. Can some one help me in this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I added below code and started working for me.

```
mws_vpc_sg.add_ingress_rule(peer= ec2.Peer.ipv4('172.30.0.0/15'), connection = ec2.Port.tcp_range(31000,655353))
```

This will produce

```
MerchWebServicesSecurityGroup4BA36B9B:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: EC2 Services Security Group
      GroupName: MerchWebServicesSecurityGroup
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          Description: Allow all outbound traffic by default
          IpProtocol: "-1"
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - CidrIp: 172.30.0.0/15
          Description: from 172.30.0.0/15:31000-655353
          FromPort: 31000
          IpProtocol: tcp
          ToPort: 655353
      VpcId: vpc-839227e7
```

Answer (score 0):

You give it a `Port` type argument. See [Port documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_ec2/Port.html#aws_cdk.aws_ec2.Port).

So something in lines of `aws_ec2.Port(aws_ec2.TCP, 31000, 65535)` should do the trick.

Comment: I gave something like this mws_vpc_sg.connections.allow_to(other =mws_vpc_sg_alb,port_range=ec2.Port(ec2.Port.tcp, 'string', 31000, 65535)) but it gave me error TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given